# ms powershell: how to handle json- objects?

Tags: json, powershell

I have a file with content

```
{
  "Names" : {"first" : "Chuck", "second" : "Norris"},
  "Numbers" : {"one" : "1", "two" : "2"}
}
```

I can read/write and convert it with ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json, this is no problem. And I can change f.e. "Chuck" into "Carlos Ray".
But how can I

- add a new tuple like f.e. Months ("1st" : "January" ...)
- add a row inside an existing tuple, f.e. "Numbers" -> "three" : 3
- delete a row
- delete a tuple

? That means: I want to read the file and convert it into $variable, modify the $variable and convert and write the file.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
$json = @'
{
  "Names" : {"first" : "Chuck", "second" : "Norris"},
  "Numbers" : {"one" : "1", "two" : "2"}
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

> Add a new tuple like f.e. Months ("1st" : "January" ...)

```
$json.PSObject.Properties.Add(
    [psnoteproperty]::new(
        'Months',
        [pscustomobject]@{ '1st' = 'January' }))
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

> Add a row inside an existing tuple, f.e. "Numbers" -> "three" : 3

```bash
$json.Numbers.PSObject.Properties.Add(
    [psnoteproperty]::new('three', '3'))
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

> Delete a row

Removing the added `Months` property from 1st example.

```bash
$json.PSObject.Properties.Remove('Months')
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

> Delete a tuple

Removing the added `three` object.

```bash
$json.Numbers.PSObject.Properties.Remove('three')
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 1):

To **complement [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77496803/45375)**:

**[`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)** is PowerShell's cmdlet for parsing JSON text into *object graphs*.

- In ***Windows PowerShell***, you ***invariably* get `[pscustomobject]` graphs**, and Santiago's answer shows you how to work with those.
- In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, you have the *option* to get (ordered) **[`[hashtable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) graphs**, using the **`-AsHashTable`** switch.

***Hashtable*-based object graphs** are generally **lighter-weight** and **better suited to later *modification***, such as in your case:

```
# PS 7+ ONLY
$fromJson = @'
{
  "Names" : {"first" : "Chuck", "second" : "Norris"},
  "Numbers" : {"one" : "1", "two" : "2"}
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

# --- UDPATE / ADDITION operations

# Update a nested entry.
$fromJson.Names.first = 'Carlos Ray'

# Add a new top-level entry
$fromJson.Months = [ordered] @{ '1st' = 'January'}

# Add a new nested entry
$fromJson.Numbers.three = 3

# Print the state of the hahstable now.
$fromJson | Out-Host

# --- REMOVAL operations

# Remove a top-level entry
$fromJson.Remove('Names')

# Remove a nested entry
$fromJson.Numbers.Remove('two')

$fromJson | Out-Host
```

Output:

```
# After entry updates / additions.
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Names                          {[first, Carlos Ray], [second, Norris]}
Numbers                        {[one, 1], [two, 2], [three, 3]}
Months                         {[1st, January]}


# After entry removals.
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Numbers                        {[one, 1], [three, 3]}
Months                         {[1st, January]}
```

**Note**:

- In PowerShell **7.3+**, `-AsHashtable` returns a graph of [`[System.Management.Automation.OrderedHashtable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.OrderedHashtable) instances, which preserve the *entry-definition order*, just like PowerShell's `[ordered] @{ ... }` hashtables<sup>[1]</sup>; in v7.2-, they were regular [`[System.Collections.Hashtable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable) instances.
- Either way, however, in order to be JSON-compliant, the **hashtables returned by `ConvertFrom-Json` are case-*sensitive*** with respect to key lookups, unlike PowerShell's regular hashtables (`@{ ... }`, `[ordered] @{ ... }`).
- **Choosing whether to use `-AsHashTable` or not**:

  - While using hashtable object graphs is generally preferable (lighter-weight, easier to modify), there are situations where obtaining `[pscustomobject]` graphs is still a must, given that hashtables and objects aren't fully interchangeable.

    - See [GitHub issue #13104](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13104) for an example and a discussion.
  - Conversely, if your JSON contains object with property names that are mere *case variations* of each other, `-AsHashTable` is a *must*, given that true *property* access in PowerShell is inherently case-*insensitive*; e.g.:

    ```
    # !! FAILS, because a [pscustomobject] instance cannot
    # !! have property names that differ in case only.
    '{ "foo": 1, "FOO": 2 }' | ConvertFrom-Json

    # OK - the hashtable returned is case-sensitive.
    '{ "foo": 1, "FOO": 2 }' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable
    ```

---

<sup>[1] These literals become [`[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary) instances, which, in fact, the `OrderedHashtable` implementation uses behind the scenes as well, albeot case-*sensitively*.</sup>